# How to get to a standardized representation of time in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

We just upgraded Pandas on a machine.  The new version is 0.24.2.  Code that previously worked (unfortunately no record of exactly which Pandas we had but I'm told it was version 0.19.X for some X) now gives this warning:

`foo.py:112: FutureWarning: Passing timedelta64-dtype data is deprecated, will raise a TypeError in a future version foo(x)`

Line 112 in that file is just literally `foo(x)`, which is a function that we wrote.  It is not raising the warning directly.  Digging into the function it appears that the actual issue is on a call in that function `foo` that looks like this:

```
df.time = pd.to_datetime(df.time).dt.time
```

Here `df` is a Pandas data frame that has been populated by calls to an external library and `pd` is aliased to `pandas`.  This construct was arguably a hack and had the effect of working around the field `time` being of various types on return from other functions, e.g. `timedelta64` one time and maybe another "timelike" type another time, depending on which libraries got called.

I've read several questions and answers here and elsewhere about the complications of representing time in general.  That's not directly relevant here as the use case here is pretty specific.  We need wall-clock time-of-day without reference to any particular date.  For example, "12:37" on the clock but with no reference to which day of the week, year, century, etc. that it is.  We also work in a specific timezone, so there are no issues of internationalization or even issues of different zones in a single country. At the same time, we call out to third-party libraries that make use of multiple representations in Python, Numpy, and Pandas that handle those more complicated cases.  The line above had served as a perfectly suitable bridge that caught all known cases, but apparently it is now deprecated.

It's not clear what the work around should be here.  Is there a function in the 0.24.2 API that will serve this role of standardizing, for lack of a better word, the representation of time between the various options floating around Python, Numpy, and Pandas into something repeatable?  We could, of course, enumerate the cases that we encounter and do some sort of manual conversion for each, but it would be nice to avoid that if possible.

Comment: `df.time = pd.to_timedelta(df.time)` would be a better choice.

Comment: I've had this error before when using standard library `datetime` objects in pandas code. Converting to pandas datetime using `pd.Timestamp()` worked for me. Maybe try `pd.Timestamp(df.time)` however, this error shouldn't happen with the line of code you've provided as `pd.to_datetime()` should already return the correct type

Comment: @Mark It is returning the right type but the usage is apparently deprecated. We're good until that happens, other than getting this warning all over the place.

Comment: We're trying to get away from the `timedelta`, @QuangHoang, so I'm not clear what you're suggesting.  We want a time.

Comment: The error says you should not pass `timedelta64` into `pd.to_datetime`. I suggested `pd.to_timedelta(df.time)`, and forgo the `.dt.time`. But apparently, your `df.time` is already `timedelta64`.

Comment: The *problem* is that my time is a `timedelta64`. Maybe this is part of the difference in the API?  The result of what I had did *not* give me a `timedelta64`.  the `.dt.time` part game me a time - I think a `datetime.time` to be specific. @QuangHoang  What you're suggesting looks like it ensures that my problem propagates rather than addressing it. At no point do I *ever* want a `timedelta64`, although, due to calling external libraries, sometimes I get one that I need to convert.

Comment: It's better to use 'transform' with a custom function that checks types and  does the required conversions: df.time=df.time.transform(fcustom())